# OpenGL Fade in / fade out a texture2D

Tags: opengl, textures

I am writing an application that displays .jpg files that are stored as Texture2D (RGB) in OpenGL. I want to smoothly change from one texture2D to the next by fading to black, then fading into the next texture.

After looking for some explanation I wrote something like this.

```
void renderTexture()
{
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture);

  gluSphere(mQuad, 1.0f, 50, 50);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

void fadeToBlack()
{
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  for (GLfloat alpha = 1.0; alpha > 0.0; alpha -= 0.05)
  {
    glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, alpha);
    renderTexture();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
  }

  glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not fade to black but instead switches to black immediately. I must have some misunderstanding on how GL_BLEND is working here. Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?

** EDIT: This did the trick. Thanks a lot j-p and Benjamin for the pointers **

```
void fadeToBlack()
{
  for (GLfloat alpha = 1.0; alpha > 0.0; alpha -= 0.001)
  {
    renderTexture();
    glColor4f(alpha, alpha, alpha, alpha);

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
  }
  glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: try `glColor4f(1.0,1.0, 1.0, alpha);` with the default pipeline, each color component are multiplied I think.

Comment: also benjamin is right, this kind of update should not be in rendering loop, but in an update frame loop in which you decrement alpha by step at each pass, not in a loop => update_func { alpha>0=>alpha--}

Comment: It does fade, but to white! Strange, how would I get it to fade black please?

Comment: you may use alpha in each component: glColor4f(alpha,alpha,alpha,alpha). Is your clearColor white?

Comment: Sorry I am completely clear on the update frame loop. Do you mean a callback function such as glutDisplayFunc()?

Comment: I have glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); so should be black I think.

Comment: glColor4f(alpha,alpha,alpha,alpha) seems to keep the texture (no fading happpening). Then instead of moving to the next picture, the screen is fully black.

Comment: try alpha=0 for the clear color, and the `idle` callback is usualy a good place to update frame data (but I'm not a glut addict) That's strange that alpha in each components makes no fading ...

Comment: It seems to have no effect to use alpha = 0 for glClearColor(). I'm wondering why it would though, by using glColor4f() isn't just trying to blend that color and the texture?

Comment: I got it to work by getting rid of the blending. It is kind of weird, I actually don't completely get why it works.

Comment: I have to doublecheck, but I think current color components is always multiplied by texture fragments, and you are normaly blending backbuffer content, thus (0,0,0,0), too tired to compute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop will be executing so quickly that the texture changes will appear to happen instantly.

Comment: Changed the loop to: for (GLfloat alpha = 1.0; alpha > 0.0; alpha -= 0.00005). It still switches to black instantly (and then the loop takes a few second to execute).